# How to set an indicator for selection in drop down on UI

Tags: website-design, forms, gui-design, html

I have a drop down on which multiple selections can be made. Here is the [demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/checkboxMenu.xhtml).

Now, if you see the example, I can select multiple options, but when I close the drop down, I don't know what have I selected. The example lists the selected option in a data list below after the form is submitted, but that is not an elegant way to do that and as the demo is a pretty basic, I didn't expect it to be doing it in elegant way either.

How can I indicate that there are some values selected in the drop down and what options do I have? I was thinking of some icon to put along the drop down, but then couldn't figure out which one to put?

Comment: How does this look for solution to this? http://s16.postimg.org/80nk3lbat/Drop_Down_Selected.png

Comment: that looks much better!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like the way Facebook and other show lists of people. A possibility would be:

No selection:

[image]

One city selected:

[image]

Two cities:

[image]

More than two:

[image]

Hover to see selection without opening (maybe with something more elegant than a title attribute):

[image]

*Finally, if all options are checked:

[image]

Comment: The answer is crisp and exact to the point.

Comment: Thanks. I added one more screenshot. If all options are selected, the UI could say so.

Comment: Yeah this is apt and a must handled condition

Comment: Thats pretty nice.

Answer (score 1):

After selection change the label od a dropdown from 'cities' to '2 cities selected'. This will give user info about two things: something is selected + quick recall of what could be inside.